# How can I have recursive Data Template for my Custom Control

Tags: wpf, xaml, dynamicresource

I have a Custom Control, which is basically a kind of a TreeView. Now the thing is I need to have any level of detail in my TreeView control so I came up with the following data template

I have the following Generic.xaml

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="treetemplate">
    <StackPanel>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}" ></TextBlock>
     <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource treetemplate}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}" x:Key="testkey">
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <local:AnythingToListConverter x:Key="anyconv"></local:AnythingToListConverter>
    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Root, Converter={StaticResource anyconv}}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource treetemplate}"  />
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource testkey}" />
</Style>
```

Here is my custom control constructor

```
        this.Root = new Node();

        this.Root.Label = "Root";
        this.Root.Children = new List<Node>();

        this.Root.Children.Add(new Node(){Label="Child1"});
        this.DataContext = this;
```

And this is how control looks like

[image: Control]

**Here is what I think the problem is**
 For the Recursive call of same template, I am using `DynamicResource`. Which never worked on my and the actual resource never got called. If I change that to `StaticResource`, it will not compile, because it won't see itself. How do I fix it ?

Full solution can be [downloaded here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/102mp8xs1iyhumo/WpfCustomControlLibrary2.zip?dl=0).

Answer (score 3):

What you need is **[HierarchicalDataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate(v=vs.110).aspx)**. It's designed to pinpoint exactly this scenario. 
Here is how you use it:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" 
                          DataType="{x:Type local:Node}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}" ></TextBlock>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Note that using this template, we have to set its `DataType` to the Type of your data item (in this case I guess it's `Node`). Also I guess you don't need any custom control for this, just use the default `TreeView` with this template defined as some resource like this:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Root, Converter={StaticResource anyconv}}">
</TreeView>
```

If you still want to keep your code, try just replacing your `ItemsControl` with `TreeView` or some `HeaderedItemsControl`. The `HierarchicalDataTemplate` is used only for `HeaderedItemsControl` (`TreeView` is also just a kind of `HeaderedItemsControl`).